# SharePoint hosted app - valid app package always NO

Tags: app, sharepoint-hosted-app

[image]

While publishing a SharePoint hosted app file to the App catalog site it always shows

> Valid App Package: No

And App Version is always 1.0.0.0.

I changed the version in `AppManifest.xml` from Visual Studio but still it shows in app catalog site as 1.0.0.0

Is there any way to make valid app package?

Answer (score 0):

I had this on my on premise environment.

I performed my research and development for a new SharePoint hosted app using SharePoint online.  later when deploying to my SharePoint 2013 on-premise farm, I received the same error "Valid App Package": No.

So in the app manifest, I changed `SharePointMinVersion` from 16.0.0.0 to 15.0.0.0 and the app uploaded successfully.

```
<App xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/2012/app/manifest"
     Name="TrisCorpFacilitiesApp"
     ProductID="{ee26a203-5378-41fb-ac2a-4e10a36ecca9}"
     Version="1.0.0.42"
     SharePointMinVersion="15.0.0.0"
>
```