# Sharepoint 2013 on premise app "Valid App Package NO"

Tags: 2013, app

Have problem when i've updated apps

[image]
After updating app shows that "Valid App Package" NO

Solutions like here: [SharePoint hosted app - valid app package always NO](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/160585/sharepoint-hosted-app-valid-app-package-always-no) doesn't work, i have 15.0.0.0 already

Could you help me what is a problem, or where i can see logs about it?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was after second deploy "feature" has been renamed, re-creating app with new Product Id solved problem!

Tip! name you features before first deploy :)