# Valid App Package columb show No for a new uploaded App (On Premesis SharePoint)

Tags: sharepoint-on-prem, spfx-webparts

Hello I am new to SharePoint, I have developed a hello world WebPart for my on premises SharePoint as shown in the [SPF tutorials available on Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hYrP6D4FaaU&list=PLR9nK3mnD-OXvSWvS2zglCzz4iplhVrKq&index=3)
similarly I followed the tutorial for uploading a WebPart after building its package file to the App Catalog as shown in the [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BpJ01ahxbiY&index=4&list=PLR9nK3mnD-OXvSWvS2zglCzz4iplhVrKq) but as I upload the package file to the App Catalog Apps for SharePoint tab I came to know that in the tutorials under the column Valid App Package there is 'Yes' while in my case it shown 'No' and due to which the WebPart App is not available in the create new app options.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: SPFX webpart doesn't support SharePoint 2013. So make sure your using Office 365 or SharePoint 2016 Premise.

Comment: Yes i am using SharePoint 2016

Comment: Is your web-part work fine with SharePoint workbench?

Comment: Yes its working fine on the local SharePoint Workbench

Comment: Hey nick, Please refer this https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/160585/sharepoint-hosted-app-valid-app-package-always-no answer I think it will help you

Comment: Thankx Bharat Khunti, but it didnt work :\

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/72097/discussion-between-bharat-khunti-and-nick).